# Visual studio continuous deployment of a Webapp does not work

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-web-app-service

I cannot deploy using the build created by the integration between Azure and VSO.
The build finishes correctly, but it is not deployed on the website! The bin folder is there. But there is no folder for the views! 
I have the impression it started when I create an webjob in the solution.
I cannot publish it neither!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're actually publishing the web job (is the project just a console app?) to the webapp, instead of the web project.

(Side note, this is one way to get a web job deployed and running)

You can control which project in your solution is being deployed by adding a new setting under "app settings" on the "configure" tab for the webapp.
The setting you want is `Project` and it's a relative path from the solution root to the .csproj file of your web project.

Alternatively, you can specify the setting in a custom .deployment file.

[Relevant Kudu documentation here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments)

From the documentation:

> You can specify the full path to the project file. Note that this is not a path to the solution file (.sln), but to the project file (.csproj/.vbproj). The reason for this is that Kudu only builds the minimal dependency tree for this project, and avoids building unrelated projects in the solution that are not needed by the web project.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> [config]
> project = WebProject/WebProject.csproj